# Access insert into with nested select on duplicate

Tags: ms-access, sql-insert

I was wondering how that I can make an sql statement in Access that will insert all records, but when the record is already existing, it is needed to update the record.

I have something like this:
INSERT INTO tablename (name1,name2) SELECT name1, name2 FROM othertable;

Where name1 is the unique identifier.

Comment: You can't update and insert in a single query. You will need to do those things separately.

Comment: But now I get an error if it already exists, how can I fix the error?

Comment: `insert into table1 (name1,name2) select name1,name2 from table2 where table2.name1 not in (select name1 from table1);
update table1 set name2='xyz' where table1.name1 in (select name1 from table1);`

Comment: @AlexGawkins valid solution, was just about to post something similar, except SQL statement chaining is not allowed in MS Access, they will need to be separate queries.

Comment: It is 2 separate SQL statements and must be executed separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single query:

[Update and Append Records with One Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227504/how-to-regularly-update-ms-access-table-from-linked-txt-file/45239813#45239813)